# how to get all posts User by User in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I have a simple blog app and I want to show "all posts" submitted by users in blocks in my home page. I mean i want to have each users posts in block section.
my model is like this:

```
'''
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
'''
```

I expect that loop through all users and all of the posts created by them and show them in my home page, but i cant get them USER by USER. 
[Please take a look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnG5r.jpg)
So how should i write my model or query the database to get desired result has shown above?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Build an object and pass it to the template.

```
users = Users.objects.all()
nested_posts = {}
for user in users:
    posts = user.post_set
    nested_posts[user] = posts
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% for user, posts in nested_posts %}
Posts for the user "{{user}}":
{% for post in posts %}
Post:{{post.id}}, Body:{{post.body}}, Date:{{post.date}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but it did not work well. it just returns user name and post title  like this:   <User: john>: "  <QuerySet [<Post: test post111>, <Post: test post blah blah>, <Post: some post>]>, <User: ela>: <QuerySet [<Post: another post>]>} " and also i want access other feilds like date, body and ....

Comment: You only need to add another loop for posts and render the fields you want. I am updating the ans.